# AWS OpsWorks package won't install

Tags: amazon-web-services, package, ubuntu-14.04, aws-opsworks, munin

I am using AWS OpsWorks to manage our servers. I have a "Chef 11 Stack" with a "Custom" layer, instance server is running outside of AWS and is Ubuntu 14.04.

I set it all up and added a bunch of packages and they all installed properly, accounts are all working, everything is working great.

A couple days later I realized I forgot a package (munin-node) and went back to the layer and added it, then clicked save. The package shows in the list of OS Packages on the Recipes tab, but it never installed. This package has previously installed properly on other layers.

I am very new to OpsWorks, I am not even sure where to start looking to see why it failed. Any suggestions on how I can get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I guess it doesn't happen automatically. Go to your instance in the AWS OpsWorks admin, click "Run Command" at the top right, select "Install Dependencies" from the dropdown, click "Install Dependencies" at the bottom right. That will install any new packages and update any existing ones.